# Resize width of Position:Fixed div to make it responsive / fluid

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a sidebar to which I am attaching a fixed class to make it sticky on scroll.

```
.fixed { position:fixed;top:0;bottom: 45px;min-height: 0 !important; }
```

But once the class gets activated the sidebar width is not working and so its messing the responsive layout once we start scrolling.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/FyrRm/

I am not sure how to resize the fixed:position sidebar to fit it responsively. I tried using `calc` but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Didn't take into account resizing from smaller to bigger

---

Add this to `$(document).ready`:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        $(".sticky").width($("#sidebar > img").width());
}).resize();
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/bLkLJ/)

Comment: Not sure if this fixed the issue.... can you check once more. It fails on browser resize