# Scrollable div with Variable Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want my sidebar to have a scrollable div. But it cant have a fixed height. How can I make it scrollable without setting a fixed height?

I tried with this, doesn't work properly.

```
.sidebar {width:300px; padding:10px; background:#efefef;height:100%; position:fixed}
.scroll-widget {overflow-y: scroll;padding:10px;margin:10px; background:#fffeee; height:inherit}
```

-

```
<div class=sidebar>
 ...
    <div class=scroll-widget>
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/YK47P

Jquery alternative is also fine with me. But i am a beginner, so please be kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I was able to make it work using jQuery and taking help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144454).

```
    $(function () { // window load
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var sidebarH = $('.sidebar').height();
            var scrollH = $('.top').height();
            $('.scroll-widget').height(sidebarH - scrollH);
        }).resize();
    });
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/YK47P/40/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `overflow: scroll` to your sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#efefef;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YK47P/1/)**

Comment: But I want the scrollbar to be visible only for `scroll-widget`

Comment: @DebajyotiDas I don't get what you means, only `scroll-widget` scrollbar is visible in your demo, isn't it?

Comment: I don't want a scrollbar for sidebar.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas no I means the demo in your question

Comment: Dont want any scrollbar for `.sidebar` only for `.scroll-content` Your solutions adds scroll bar for both the divs